# 'Binding' Bash Curly Braces

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In Bash,

```
echo a{b,c}d{e,f}
```

prints

```
abde    abdf    acde    acdf
```

The output I'd like to see is

```
abde    acdf
```

In other words, given *N* parameters, I'd like Bash to use the *i*th parameter within each pair of braces to construct *N* strings.

Comment: _N_ is the number of arguments between the curly braces.

Comment: Writing it as `{bde,cdf}` is not an option? Then you're probably left with a for loop and indexing arrays or something like that.

Comment: Actually, these are the two types of commands I was hoping to merge:
`git rm src/test/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/AppTest.java`
and
`git rm src/main/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/App.java`

Comment: braces just control output. They aren't wildcards. As frostschutz suggested, what you are asking is `a{bde,cdf}` - two distinct endings that happen to have a middle character in common. If those two are files that exist, you could say `a[bc]d[ef]`, but that predicates filename expansion and existence of the files (with no `acde` or `abdf`). You could as easily just `echo abde acdf`. Give us more info. Otherwise this is just "I wish it worked this way," which it definitely does not.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with arrays:

```
$ foo=( b c ); bar=( e f ); for i in {0..1}; do echo a${foo[$i]}d${bar[$i]}; done
abde
acdf
```

I assume your actual use case is a bit more complex, so if you populate the arrays using another command and don't necessarily know their size, you can use:

```
foo=( b c ); bar=( e f ); for i in $(seq 0 $((${#foo[@]}-1))); do 
   echo a${foo[$i]}d${bar[$i]}; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly answer, but here it is anyway:

```
$ echo a{b,c,d}e{f,g,h} | awk 'BEGIN {N=3;} { for (i=0; i<N; i++) { print $(i*N+i+1) } }'

$ echo a{b,c,d,1}e{f,g,h,2} | awk 'BEGIN {N=4;} { for (i=0; i<N; i++) { print $(i*N+i+1) } }'

$ echo a{b,c,d,1,A}e{f,g,h,2,Z} | awk 'BEGIN {N=5;} { for (i=0; i<N; i++) { print $(i*N+i+1) } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way braces work.

If there is a string that doesn't appear in the text, say `,`, you can apply successive string substitutions to an array:

```
a=(,b,e @c,f)
a=("${a[@]/,/a/}")
a=("${a[@]/,/d}")
echo "${a[@]}"
```

A loop would be clearer though. If you want to stick the pieces together, you can use a separator that doesn't eappear in the strings, say `,` which would be special inside braces anyway.

```
a=(); IFS=,; set -f
for x in b,e c,f; do
  a+=(a${x%*,}d${x#*,})
done
```

Another approach is to define two parallel arrays.

```
version=(test main)
files=(AppTest.java App.java)
for ((i=0; i<${#files}; i++) rm "src/$version[i]/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/files[i].java"
```

I think the easiest way to deal with this specific command would be to define a function.

```
rmapp () { rm "src/$1/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/$2.java"; }
```

Comment: I think the function is the cleanest solution. All those loops look ugly (which is why I can't upvote this entire answer, alas).